# VB .Net DataGridView ComboBox - How do you reference shown text that's not saved yet?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

Here's the issue:

I have a datagridview that's tied to an empty dataset (typically, unless orders weren't finished from the last session). The user keys in a jobNumber and deliveryDate into the first 2 columns, then if they have a custom email address that needs to be used they can select it from the combobox (populated with previously used addresses on formLoad) or type out a new email if it doesn't exist. The problem is if the email entered doesn't match one in the combobox list then it removes it on tab.

I have tried a bunch of different things to access the shown (user typed) value before it's erased by the commit, but can't seem to find a way. My work around is as shown below.. I'm basically capturing the keystrokes into the combobox by a custom handler. Then I add it to the combobox list, and select that value. Works ok, but can get confused depending on how you access the combobox.

Any thoughts on trying to capture the entire string entered by the user before it's erased by the commit?

```
Private Sub dGrid1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dGrid1.EditingControlShowing
    If TypeOf e.Control Is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl Then
        RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf cBox_KeyDown

        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

        holdThis = ""
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf cBox_KeyDown
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True

        holdThis = holdThis.Substring(1)

        Dim cBoxCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        cBoxCol = dGrid1.Columns.Item(3)
        cBoxCol.Items.Add(holdThis)
        cBoxCol = dGrid1.Columns.Item(4)
        cBoxCol.Items.Add(holdThis)

        dGrid1.CurrentCell.Value = holdThis
        Dim iCol = dGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Dim iRow = dGrid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        If iCol = dGrid1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            If iRow < dGrid1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                dGrid1.CurrentCell = dGrid1(0, iRow + 1)
            End If
        Else
            dGrid1.CurrentCell = dGrid1(iCol + 1, iRow)
        End If

        holdThis = ""
    Else
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            holdThis = Strings.Left(holdThis, holdThis.Length - 1)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.ShiftKey And Keys.D2 Then
            holdThis = holdThis & "@"
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.OemPeriod Then
            holdThis = holdThis & "."
        Else
            If holdThis.Length > 1 Then
                If holdThis(holdThis.Length - 1) = "2" Then
                    holdThis = Strings.Left(holdThis, holdThis.Length - 1)
                End If
            End If

            holdThis = holdThis & Chr(e.KeyValue)
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of a ComboBox in the grid, have you tried using a regular TextBox and setting its AutoComplete properties? It would have similar functionality to a ComboBox, but being a TextBox anything entered would saved with no additional interaction

Comment: Not a bad idea actually.. I'm sure it would of been a bit easier to implement now that you mention it. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Also it works on tab now instead of relying on the user pressing space... Here's the code that allows you access to the uncommited value in the datagridview combobox.

```
Private Sub dGrid1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dGrid1.EditingControlShowing
    If TypeOf e.Control Is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl Then
        RemoveHandler e.Control.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf cBox_PreviewKeyDown

        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Append

        AddHandler e.Control.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf cBox_PreviewKeyDown
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cBox_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
    Dim cBox As DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl = sender
    Dim val As Object = cBox.Text

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        Dim cBoxCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

        'SO E-Mail Col
        cBoxCol = dGrid1.Columns.Item(3)
        cBoxCol.Items.Add(val)
        'ADC E-Mail Col
        cBoxCol = dGrid1.Columns.Item(4)
        cBoxCol.Items.Add(val)

        'Set cBox Value
        dGrid1.CurrentCell.Value = val
    End If
End Sub
```